# sign out function flutter using sharedpreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I need a little help about signing out using shared preferences.
I got here functional code snippet which is from the MainMenu class.

```
class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {

  
  final VoidCallback signOut;

  MainMenu(this.signOut);
  

  @override
  _MainMenuState createState() => _MainMenuState();
}

class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> {

  int index = 0;
 

  List<Widget> list = [
    HomeScreen(),
    Stations(),
    AccountPage(),

    
  ];

  signOut() {
    setState(() {
      widget.signOut();
    });
  }
```

I want it to be transfered or be called in my other class which is here. MyDrawer class.

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
    
  final Function onTap;
    MyDrawer(
    {this.onTap
    });



    @override
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

    
 class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
```

And this code snippet where I saved the prefrences of the signOut().

```
signOut() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      preferences.setInt("value", null);
      preferences.setString("fname", null);
      preferences.setString("lname", null);
      preferences.setString("email", null);
      preferences.setString("address", null);
      preferences.setString("mobile", null);    
      preferences.setString("date", null);   
      preferences.setString("id", null);

      preferences.commit();
      _loginStatus = LoginStatus.notSignIn;
    });
  }
```

I have also made a switch case for the login status.

```
    switch (_loginStatus) {
      case LoginStatus.notSignIn:
       return Scaffold(
    break;

      case LoginStatus.signIn:
        return MainMenu(signOut);

        break;
```

What I want is to get the access of signOut method in my MyDrawer class. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just call the sign out method in whatever place you want it to be

Comment: You can move the function to another class and use the class to call it from both MyDrawer and MainMenu

Comment: @Zaza.codes i've tried calling it on my MyDrawer class but it gives an exception The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()

Comment: @Trizin it's on  a class called Login()

Comment: It's not a good coding practice but you can just copy the method and put it in your MyDrawer class, I'm not really understanding your code or what you want to do but creating the same method in your MyDrawer class should work properly

Comment: @Zaza.codes that's what i did. and that null exception came out. I think maybe on the switch case on loginstatus?

Comment: I just took a proper look at your code and saw that you are setting all the values to null, why not just clear everything you stored on sharedPreferences with preferences.clear(); ? and also there is a proper way to check for login status which is by checking for the token or whatever value it is you need to be able to know if the user has logged in or not, you could check it out here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580019/how-to-check-auth-token-at-entry-point-of-flutter-app